# NestJs: multiple views directory

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I am developing an MVC app using nestJs framework, and I used the hbs template-engine.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mvc) I have to use this configuration to make nestjs able to serve views:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule);

  app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));
  app.setBaseViewsDir(join(__dirname, '..', 'views'));
  app.setViewEngine('hbs');

  await app.listen(3000);
}
```

This configuration assumes that all views are located in one directory (views) but what if every module has its own views?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Since v5.7.0

You can set an array of directories:

```
app.setBaseViewsDir([
  join(__dirname, '..', 'users/views'), 
  join(__dirname, '..', 'books/views'),
]);
```

---

## Before v5.7.0

In express, you can [set an array of base path directories](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.set):

> A directory or an array of directories for the application's views. If an array, the views are looked up in the order they occur in the array.

However, the typings in nest.js do not allow for an array, see [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1513). I've created a [pull request](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/1514), that will change that.

Until the pull request is merged, you can do:

```
app.setBaseViewsDir([
    join(__dirname, '..', 'users/views'), 
    join(__dirname, '..', 'books/views'),
  ] as any);
```

As soon as the pull request is merged, you can remove the `as any`.

Comment: Thanks! it works. but by this method all the "src" folder will be exposed as public right ? is this safe ?

Comment: I think it only gets exposed when you set `useStaticAssets` (which you don't have to). Views should only be accessible when you explicitly expose them via `@Render`.

Comment: @maroodb not a solution for you?

Comment: But it does not expose any files publicly unless you explicitly reference them in `@Render`. And even if you have your views directory next to your src directory, you can access views in the src directory by using relative paths: `../src/my-view`, but again only with `@Render`. So there's no difference.

Comment: @maroodb I've added a better option to my answer. :-)

Comment: this makes sense!

Comment: Oh, what happened? Ran into a problem?

Comment: Sorry, it was a undesired click :p

Comment: The correct typings are available from version v5.7.0

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you have an app structure similar to this:

```
src
  main.ts
  /users
       users.controller.ts
       /views
         my-view.hbs
  /books
       books.controller.ts
       /views
         my-view.hbs
```

Then you can set the base view dir to `src`:

```
app.setBaseViewsDir(__dirname);
```

And reference the view with its relative path in your controllers:

```
@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {

  @Render('users/views/my-view')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  @Get()
  async getMyView() {
```

Comment: iam not able to achieve this, Failed to lookup view

Comment: @SaurabhYadav This too general to be answered. Please open a new question and include the relevant code snippets. Also, see the other answer above, maybe this will work for you.

Comment: in main.ts I have set  app.setBaseViewsDir(__dirname);
 all thing are same as you have mentioned in answer. I have also created a git repo for this https://github.com/saurabhkhoshya/nestjs-mvc-handlebar

Comment: it be great if you have any sample for this https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1513

Comment: You can even create the render path from ```__dirname``` to avoid coupling controller with the path of the feature folder. A basic example would be:
```@Render(__dirname + '/views/my-view')```